# Is TaffyDB still valid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, taffydb

I tried to install TaffyDB using the command `npm install --production taffy` given on the [Github](https://github.com/typicaljoe/taffydb) repository and I got the warning "npm WARN deprecated taffy@2.6.2: Please do not use this package it has a major security vunability - check https://snyk.io/vuln/search?q=taffy&type=npm for details."

Is there a new version somewhere or should TaffyDB not be used anymore? If not, are there better alternatives? All I would like to do is select an item in a JSON array using a set of values in NextJS.

To be more specific, I have an array of product variants with, for simplicity, just a set of option values i.e.

```
product_variants = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "size": "medium",
    "material": "polyester"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "color": "blue",
    "size": "medium",
    "material": "polyester"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "color": "red",
    "size": "small",
    "material": "nylon"
  },
  ...
]
```

When a user clicks a selection of buttons on the product detail page e.g. `{"color":"red", "size":"small"}`, I want to be able to extract product variants matching this set of selections.

I'm new to JavaScript but not at all to programming and am unsure what I can use to achieve my objective.

Comment: Whether or not it "should" be used depends on how much the vulnerability would actually impact you. There are *many* options for simple DB-like data querying. What's "better" depends on what you're actually doing--"getting a value from an array of values based on criteria" isn't much to go on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just edited the question to explain what I would like to achieve. I have heard of jslinq, jsonsql etc. Is there one you would recommend or is there another, simpler, approach to achieve what I want?

Comment: @TommyWolheart That's a pretty serious vulnerability... I wouldn't use it anymore.  By the looks of it though, you just need `Array.filter()`.

Comment: @Brad Thanks so much! filter() does exactly what I wanted.